# What am I getting `Template is missing` on one server, but not on my local box? Both on `Master`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm getting `Template is missing` error. I did some refactoring and on my first deployment I'm getting this error. My local box is working fine, they are both on `master`.

```
[arozar@logmon csdashboard]$ git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

Error:

```
Template is missing

Missing template signatures/show, application/show with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "/opt/csdashboard/app/views"
```

On the deplyment server I have this in my  `rake routes`:

```
 Signatures GET    /Signatures(.:format)                  Signatures#show
```

And I clearly have the file on the deployment server:

```
[arozar@logmon csdashboard]$ ls -ltrh app/views/Signatures/
total 4.0K
-rw-r--r--. 1 apache apache 2.2K Aug  2 14:10 show.erb
```

Is it because of Cap [S] in `app/views/Signatures/`

Comment: I suspect it IS because of the cap S. Have you tried renaming it?

Comment: Just did, and yep that got it. I guess maybe the difference from Mac (localhost) vs CentOS (test server)... Don't really know..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HFS+ (the Mac filesystem) is [case insensitive](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/22297/is-bash-in-osx-case-insensitive), so it treats `Signatures` and `signatures` as if they were the same thing - making it work fine on your local box. CentOS on the other hand is case sensitive. So `Signatures` and `signatures` are actually pointing to different locations on disk. Rails is only going to look for files in the lower-case path and since Mac is case insensitive it `Signatures` works since the file system makes no distinction.

To fix, be consistent with the casing in your file paths.